# Does charindex count white spaces SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, charindex

Does CharIndex count the white spaces in SQL Server 2014 and if it does is there an alternative to Charindex() to ignore white spaces?

By this I mean by the example below.

```
select top 25 
    companyname, charindex ('A', companyname, 1) as 'occurences of a'
from shippers
```

and the results would look something like

- Speedy Express   0
- United Package   9
- Federal Shipping 6

I noticed that by looking at United Package it says 9 counting the white space and if not it would be 8. So if there are alternatives any of them worth sharing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`charindex` counts the white-spaces as well.

You can alternatively `replace` white-spaces with empty strings and search for the occurences of a character.

```
select top 25 companyname, 
charindex ('A',replace(companyname,' ','')) as [occurences of a]
from shippers
```